# Is the preimage of the non-normal locus a divisor?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, birational-geometry, integral-dependence

Let $X$ be a complex, affine variety. Let $\nu:\tilde X\to X$ be the normalization of $X$ and denote by $D\subseteq X$ the closed set of points where $\nu$ fails to be an isomorphism, i.e. $D$ is the non-normal locus of $X$.

**Question 1.**
Under which conditions is $D\subseteq X$ pure of codimension one? I can remove all codimension one components of $D$ and end up with a variety whose nonormal locus has codimension at least two. So, if $X$ was Cohen-Macaulay then I would already know that $D$ must be pure of codimension one. 
*Can I do with less than the Cohen-Macaulay assumption?*

**Question 2.**
Let $Z\subseteq D$ be an irreducible component of $D$. What can be said about the dimension of the irreducible components of $\nu^{-1}(Z)$?

More specifically, what can be said if $D$ is pure of codimension one - is $\nu^{-1}(D)$ also of codimension one in this case?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I don't have an answer at the moment, just a nitpick: your description of the non-normal locus as the set of points with more than one preimage is incorrect, as the cuspidal curve shows.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh: A very good nitpick, I fixed that.